PNT for primes of the form $a^3 + 2 b^3$?
It seems that primes of the form $a^3 + 2 b^3$ have the asymptotic
$$x(n) = (n+1/n)^2 \ln(n)$$
where $x(n)$ is the n th number of that kind.
Let $\pi_x(n)$ be the counting function of such numbers.
So we seem to have
$$\lim \frac{\pi_x(n)\ln(n)}{\sqrt n} = 1$$
Is this known to be true ?
edit :
D. R. Heath-Brown proved in 2001 that there are infinitely many prime numbers in this sequence.
see
https://oeis.org/A219726
and
https://ora.ox.ac.uk/objects/uuid:ebb25eb4-a19e-4049-8117-3269e140b0fe/files/m4c54e951f8057c3650de2351e0f66eb5
with thanks to user underflow.

You shouldn't use $a$ for 2 different things.

Seems bad to jse $a$ as an integer and $a(n)$ as a function having nothing to do with that integer $a.$ And then $\pi_a,$ having nothing to do with either $a?$

How high did you check the asymptote? I wouldn't be surprised if very little is known, not even whether there are infinitely many such primes.

i edited the a.
i used this here :
https://oeis.org/A173587

OEIS just collects prime numbers of this form. In fact, I also doubt that we know that infinite many primes of this form exists although heuristically this is probably the case (it already follows from the Bunyakovsky conjecture). To backup the above limit, you should present data upto at least $n=10^{12}$.

I would start with primes $a^3 + 2 b^3 + 4 c^3 - 6abc$

https://oeis.org/A040028

@WillJagy why ??

The Heath-Brown paper linked to describes what the conjecture is (with a different normalization); in particular, any limit related to this counting function should be a rational multiple of the (presumably transcendental) constant $\sigma_0 = \prod_p (1-\frac{\nu(p)-1}p)$, where $\nu(p)$ is the number of solutions to $x^3\equiv 2\pmod p$.

@GregMartin so replace $1$ in that limit by this sigma constant ?
